# Google Identiy Toolkit Random OAuth Error

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-oauth, google-identity-toolkit

I am successfully implementing Google Identity Toolkit on a Google App Engine Java server using the [Google Identity Toolkit Java client](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-java-client).

I would say I have no issues upwards of 99% of the time. On some rare instances however, possibly after rapid successive calls. I get the following error.

```
com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException: 
java.security.SignatureException: Invalid signature for token: <some-lengthy-token-string-here>
```

Tec Stack: AngularJS ngResource --> Google Cloud Endpoints (App Engine Java) --> [Google Identity Toolkit Java client](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-java-client).

I simply retry the call and no problem, but this still needs to be figured out. I am willing to post more information, but not sure where to start. My best guess is that the service won't authenticate the same token twice in a very short span of time. Anyone with more understanding of how the service works please give me some ideas.